# Java - Directly accessing an object in a list that contains a given value

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I am searching for a way in Java to directly access an object in a list that contains a given object.

what i mean is something like this

```
List<ObjectA> list = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
Objectb objb = new ObjectB();
list.add(new ObjectA(objb, new ObjectB()));

ObjectA containsObjB;
boolean gotit= false;
for(ObjectA a: list)
{
    for(ObjectB pObjB: a.getObjBs())
    {
        if(pObjB.equals(objb)
        {
            containsObjB = a;
            gotit = true;
            break;
        }
        if(gotit) break;
    }
}
```

this would be the long run around but since this operation will be really time-critical i wondered if there is a possibility to map the list so i can instant access the correct ObjectA.

Not sure if this is possible, if not any suggestion how to make that fast / faster is welcome.

Greetings
Sebastian

Comment: Time critical is one thing; what about the amount of objects stored? Ie, can you afford an extra storage? Can two objects of class `ObjectA` contain equivalent instances of `ObjectB`? If yes, what is supposed to happen in such a case? How do you define equivalence on `ObjectB` instances?

Comment: Have you looked into hashmaps? if time is so critical?

Comment: you implemented a 2D matrix there... O(1) is not possible

Answer (score 2):

well, if you're stuck using a list, and the list isn't already sorted or in a known order, you have to look at every item.

Even if you wanted to build an index/map, you'd still have to look at every item to build the map...  so if it is a one time lookup, the brute force might just be the way to go.

If this is a common occurrence, you could build some kind of index, like a Map of objb:obja, presuming each B is only in one A...

Or you could change the code so that it isn't lists of lists, it is collections optimized for lookups.

Comment: Im not stuck to a list it doesnt matter what i use to store my objects. I guess a hashmap sounds good so far i guess i'll go with this one. thx^^